# How to render UI from separte ui-xxx-xxx.R file

Tags: r, shiny

I'm using 2 file method to create an R shiny APP. I have created a navbar in file ui.R. On tab click I want to load another UI from the file. below is the code.

## Define UI for application

UI.R

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  #app title
  navbarPage("KM Plot",id="navpage",
             tabPanel("Home",id = "homePage"),
             tabPanel("UploadFile",uiOutput("uploadpage")),
             tabPanel("About",id = "aboutPage"),
             tabPanel("ContactUs",id = "contactusPage"),
             theme = "css/bootstrap.grid.css"
  ),
  tags$h1("KM-PLOT")
)
```

Server.R

```
#define server for application
server <- function(input,output)
{
    # observe(input$navpage,
    #          {
    #            print("tab bar clicked")
    #          }
    # )
  #load the page with tab clicked 
  output$uploadpage<-renderUI("ui-tab-uploadpage.R")
}
```

ui-tab-uploadpage.R

```
ui<-fluidPage()
{
  titlePanel("upload files")
  tagList(
    sliderInput("n", "N", 1, 1000, 500),
    textInput("label", "Label")
  )
}
```

I tried to find an answer for it but was unsuccessful. Need help on this

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
output$uploadpage<-renderUI("ui-tab-uploadpage.R")
```

instead this we need to modify the above function call as

```
output$uploadpage<-renderUI("ui-tab-uploadpage.R")
```